# Rails 5, Polymorphic Associations and multiple has_ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I have a rails app as follows:
A location model which stores some geo-stuff (a location basically), a post model and a user model. A post model can have a location. A user model can have a location as home location and another one as remote location:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locationable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, as: :locationable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :homelocation, as: :locationable, class_name: 'Location'
  has_one :remotelocation, as: :locationable, class_name: 'Location'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :homelocation, :remotelocation
end
```

The post and location stuff works great. If I delete one of the ´has_one´ lines from the user model and rename homelocation to location, everything works great too. If I want a user to have two different locations though, I get an 'Unpermitted parameters: homelocation, remotelocation' error when trying to save changes.

My users_controller has a

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:admin, :name, :motto, homelocation_attributes: [:id, :address], remotelocation_attributes: [:id, :address])
end
```

just as the posts_controller has a

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, location_attributes: [:id, :address])
end
```

My forms look like this:

```
.form-group.string.required.user_homelocation_address
  label.control-label.string.required for="user_homelocation_address"
    abbr title="required"
    | Home Location
  input#user_homelocation_address.form-control.string.required name="user[homelocation][address]" type="text"

.form-group.string.required.user_remotelocation_address
  label.control-label.string.required for="user_remotelocation_address"
    abbr title="required"
    | Remote Location
  input#user_remotelocation_address.form-control.string.required name="user[remotelocation][address]" type="text"
```

So why does this work for one 'has_one', but not for two?

Comment: Great explanation to all this stuff is here, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814903/deep-nested-accepts-nested-attributes-for-not-rendering-attribute-data-in-edit-t by @sirramongabriel – only sadly it seems he also couldn't figure out my problem; read the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is really that the `Location` does not know if it is the User's `homelocation` or `remotelocation`. The solution to this is to make the `User` belong to the `Location`

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :homelocation,   class_name: 'Location'
  belongs_to :remotelocation, class_name: 'Location'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :homelocation, :remotelocation
end
```

And, obviously, change the tables to match.

There is no easy way to navigate back from a `Location` to it's owner. Is this a requirement?

#### Update 1

Something I didn't say initially, and obviously with a vague understanding of the requirements, is that I consider polymorphic `belongs_to` to be one of those 'considered evil' topics. It is almost always a bad code smell, it means you can't implement foreign keys which I consider an essential practice and there are other ways to solve the problems it is trying to solve. My instinct would be to create 2 models and 2 tables, `UserLocation` and `PostLocation`.

As I said initially the problem remains, how do you know if a Location is a home location or a remote location, or in other words what does `location.locationable = some_user` set? There is no way for Rails to know and this is really what you need to solve.

Given the model above, there are ways to navigate from the `Location` to it's owner but to make it perform decently I would suggest that you add a `type` field to the `Location` table so that you know if it is a `post`, `home` or `remote` location. You could then write:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  def owner
    case type
    when 'post'   Post.where(location_id: self).first
    when 'home'   User.where(homelocation_id: self).first
    when 'remote' User.where(remotelocation_id: self).first
  end
  # or # 
  def owner
    case type
    when 'post'   Post.where(location_id: self).first
    else          User.where('homelocation_id = ? OR remotelocation_id = ?', self, self).first
  end
end
```

You could in theory do the same thing using STI wih a `Location` class and `UserLocation` and `PostLocation` subclasses.

#### Option 2

Having thought about it, I might implement this would be:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locationable, polymorphic: true
  ## Again add a `type` field ##
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, as: :locationable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations, as: :locationable, class_name: 'Location'
  has_one  :homelocation,  class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'locationable_id', -> { where(type: 'home') }
  has_one  :remotelocation,  class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'locationable_id', -> { where(type: 'remote') }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :homelocation, :remotelocation
end
```

Though my thoughts about `belongs_to polymorphic` still stand :)

In all cases, you might also need to write code to create the `homelocation` and `remotelocation` instances rather than using `accepts_nested_attributes`. Also these options would not perform well if you are retrieving many records and trying to solve the `n+1` problem.

Comment: That is not what I wanted initially, because I need to navigate back from a Location to a User ... but maybe your solution is still better for what I want anyway: I can use one of those geo-functions in a SQL-query to get all posts or users in a certain radius around a location.